# Convert existed images to base64 in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, base64

I'm trying to show the user saved images in product edit page. I'll show the images which is uploaded by the user in add product. I'm trying to convert the image to base64 format to show it in background.

when I use

```
file_get_contents
```

in my Controller it's gives me this error.

```
file_get_contents(full_path_to_image): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

My images is stored under "public/images/upload/FILE_NAME"

is there any trick that I miss or something that I make wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your upload images in public folder try:

`$path = public_path('images/upload/file_name');`

If your upload images in Storage public folder try:

`$path = storage_path('images/upload/file_name');`

To encode the image to base64 try:

`base64_encode($file_path);`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have change my code to this; file_get_contents(public_path(IMAGE_NAME)); but still the same error.

Comment: no. here is the full code ;             $filetype = pathinfo(public_path($filename),PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
return 'data:image/'.$filetype.';base64,'.base64_encode(public_path($filename)); I get the base64 format but this is not showing the image

Comment: how do you set the image?

Comment: example `<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot I have fixed with your help. Best Regards

Comment: `$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_path));` use this for converting the file not the URL as the answer mentioned here.